# Do I need CFs auto root If I can install TWRP recovery?

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I am about to try and root my Samsung galaxy note 4 and install TWRP recovery. I want to avoid any conflicting issues so I would like to know If I need to use CFs auto root first and then install TWRP recovery, or if I can just install TWRP recovery and root with that. Also is v3.10.0 the latest Odin version?

Also, will rooting and installing a custom recovery affect any phone features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rooting and installing a recovery are two entirely different processes which do not interfere with each other. If you can install a recovery without rooting (as far as I know, Odin can do this), I would suggest that you try that and then install a rooting .zip from that recovery, I highly suggest koush's Superuser, the zip can be downloaded from its [Google Play page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser). That way you aren't relying on an exploit to obtain root access.

Comment: Also, if you are planning to install a recovery, you probably are planning to install a custom ROM too. That makes rooting your current firmware useless, since it will get overwritten by the new ROM.

Comment: Yeah I will probably add a custom rom down the road, that is indeed why I'm installing TWRP, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Rooting will also disable OTA updates from your carrier too. Which again is a moot point since you are installing a custom ROM anyway. Also, some software *may* refuse to run if it detects a rooted device, but there are ways to hide that, as GiantTree said.

Comment: I have to root to backup my EFS. You said CF relies on an exploit. If I root with Cf and then try to install TWRP would it be a bad idea to sill try and install the SU zip?

Comment: No, not a bad idea. I know how that zip works and it removes every other superuser program before installing itself. If you're rooted, you can try different superuser implementations, I only suggested that because that's my favourite (Open-source, plus does everything that other versions' paid options do.) There is *probably* nothing wrong with using exploits to root the phone; I just try to avoid them because they *are*, after all, malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

First install CF Auto-Root and **then** TWRP recovery because CF Auto-Root flashes your stock recovery after rooting.

Odin 3.10.0 seems to be the latest (the last time I flashed with version 3.09).
Rooting may or may not be recognized by some banking or enterprise software as a malicious firmware modification and will make them unable to run, but luckily there are Xposed modules like [RootCloak](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-rootcloak-completely-hide-root-t2574647) that will hide root from those apps.

Comment: I don't want to go to stock recovery, I want to install TWRP. If I can install SU from TWRP like matega is saying I would prefer that.

Comment: What is the advantage of having my stock recovery flashed after rooting?

Comment: This is the way CF-AutoRoot roots your device. It reboots into its own custom recovery that automatically roots your device and then flashes back your stock recovery because your device is then already rooted. It can't preserve your custom recovery because the stock recovery comes bundled within its binary.