# How to root Android using CF-Auto Root Solution

Tags: applications

How to root using CF- auto root? How to use Odin with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need CFs auto root If I can install TWRP recovery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93135/do-i-need-cfs-auto-root-if-i-can-install-twrp-recovery)

Answer (score 1):

When you decide to root your Android usually you have to pick a proper rooting solution next. Otherwise, you have to face a lot of problems. In the worst-case, you might have a bricked mobile phone or tablet instead of a rooted one. So in this article, I'm going to talk about one of the best rooting tools if you have a Samsung smartphone or a tablet. We are going to root it using CF Auto Root through [download Odin](https://odindownload.com/root-android/).

**Preparations before Root Android**

So this an invention of the famous XDA developer [Chainfire](https://twitter.com/ChainfireXDA?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor). The exploit is working for more than 300 common Android devices.  But today we are gonna focus on Samsung. If you want to work with this you better check the compatible list which is available in the XDA Developers forum. It usually unlocks the bootloader first. So make sure to keep backups unless you will lose your data. And the other special fact is that Samsung drivers are only compatible with Windows. So you should have a Windows PC for the task.

[image]

**Android Rooting for Samsung**

- First, you have to make sure to install proper drivers. Check [this
  link](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows) out and you will be able to download them. You just have to extract the zip and launch the .exe.
- The next step is to download the correct CF-Auto-Root file. There are
  many. So to find your compatible version check the model Number and
  the Android version. And then click the download.
- Make a new folder and extract the downloaded zip file there. The file
  should be located in the hard drive.
- Then put your smartphone or the tablet into the download mode. Volume
  down button, home button, and power button will help to do this.
  Press and hold it simultaneously.
- Now connect it with the windows computer using a USB cable.
- Now browse to the folder that has extracted the content of the
  downloaded zip file. On there you will see a .exe file with a name
  ODIN. Right-click on that select to run it as an Administrator
- Once Odin is running it will detect the device.
- In the interface  "ID:COM" field should be turned to blue.

[image]

- Click the AP button and keep the rest unchanged.
- Again you have to browse to that exact same place that has extracted
  the content and select CF-Auto-Root.rar.md5 file. Then click Open
- When the log tab displays a message saying "Leave CS" click the
  start.
- Now the rooting process has been started.
- When its finished the device will reboot back to Android.

*Wrap Up*

*So this is an almighty process of rooting your Android Operating System using CF-Auto-Root and Samsung Odin. It is safe and pretty easy compared to some other tools. So if you want to check the root status you should download the root checker.*